# Can't find script engine "OfficeStarter.vbs"

Tags: vbscript, microsoft-office-starter

When I boot up my laptop, I have an error message:

Can't find script engine "VBScript" for script "C:\Program Files\WindowsUpdate\OfficeStarter.vbs

I have Windows 7 and Office Starter 2010 as a default, 
But I deleted Office starter and installed Office 2013 preview version.
I think I deleted that file "officestarter.vbs" somehow..
That file exists in that folder with 1kb size.

Do I need that file even though I don't use office starter?
How can I recover the file?

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that OfficeStarter.vbs is trying to run, but the script engine that it is trying to use (CScript.exe or WScript.exe) cannot be found, is corrupt, or is not properly registered. There are a few potential fixes. There is a discussion here: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/genuinevista/thread/1b7332ba-d1f7-455f-b523-1dc45bc2b939